# Bootstrap collapse on listview

Tags: listview

I'm still using asp.net webforms (not ok with MVC yet).
I have a listview items that contains a Bootstap collapse.
I want to retain the open pan after a postback.
I know there are some answeres, but non of it covering a listview.
Please send me a full steps answer as I'm not a pro.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, just got it:
I have passed the collapsed item ID to a hidden field (which is the id I'm using for the collapse div) and manually load the following script:

```
<script>
                 function xpand() {
                     var target = $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val();
                     $('#'+target).collapse('show');
                 }
</script>
```